# Insignificant Potential difference?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible, that a conductor with an extremely short length, say $1\text{mm}$ or less passing a magnetic field of $1T$ with a reasonable velocity of $20\text{m}/\text{s}$ would induce little to no potential difference at all, such that $0$ current $I$ would flow?

Is there a value, that's so small that current won't even flow? Regardless if there is Potential Difference (being very small)?

**Edit**:
Using the following formula : $\epsilon$ = -$vBL$,
since the conductor is entering the magnetic field, and exiting it while connected to a circuit.

Comment: What does $PD$ mean?

Comment: Do you mean passing *through* a magnetic field? Normally, a 'conductor' does not have a potential difference across it, as it is effectively a 'short-circuit'. For this reason, a surface of a conductor is considered an equipotential surface (no potential difference).

Comment: Edited the questions for a bit more clarification.

Comment: The difference between "little" and "no" in physics is a complicated matter. You can make the potential as small as you like by making l as small as you like, but you can't make l=0. There is no such thing as a conductor of zero length.

Comment: Yes there will be an emf since the magnetic flux through the closed conducting loop is changing...
BY Faraday's law

Comment: Here the Lorentz force is working

Comment: Yea, I assumed the same, but for some reason I thought maybe the force is not strong enough to actually allow current flow. But never mind that, thanks!